# SMTP commands for "AUTH NTLM"

Tags: smtp, ntlm

I'm failing at finding the commands I need to send to authenticate to a SMTP server using NTLM.

I think it goes something like:

```
AUTH NTLM <bae64encode something>
334
<bae64encode something>
235
```

Comment: You may want to be more specific about your environment, etc. Authorization in the SMTP RFC probably doesn't include any support for NTLM so I would assume you're using Exchange or something that extends the original spec, but you know what they say about assuming.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a Base64-encoded Type 1 message.  [Read this](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/ntlm.html).

Comment: I've never been very good at reading RFCs, if you could give me an example I would be better able to read that RFC next time I need it.

Comment: Click the link. Scroll down looking for "example".

Answer (score 5):

i think the following liknk might be helpful for you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246870%28v=prot.10%29.aspx

You need to encode everything and follow NTLM authentifaction protocol.